# Is there any mechanism in jsonschema to define custom validators for arrays?

Tags: jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I would like the ability to write a jsonschema fragment like:

```
{
   "type":"array",
   "items":{
      "type":"number",
      "lag":2
   }
}
```

which succeeds on an array of numbers whose values are all 2 apart: eg

```
[ 1, 3, 5, 7 ]
```

I am able to describe the custom format as a function from list to bool.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No there is not. You can find the available array validations here:
https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.4

You can specify that a number must be a multiple of x:
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html#multiples
but of course this only does part of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Restricting the set to a multiple of x does not do "part of what" the OP wants to do, unless x = 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally mean odd number, you can do:

```
{
   "type":"array",
   "items":{
      "allOf": [{"type":"number"}, {"not": {"multipleOf": 2}}],
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. I defined a custom validator https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/creating/.
Unfortunately I have to do validation inside the validator that the instance is an array of numbers.